# Spring Boot 2.2.2 and "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=(create|create-drop|update|validate)" not working

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hbm2ddl

My application is based on Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE and PostgreSQL. I am relying on Spring's AutoConfiguration as far as persistence is concerned. My application.properties file contains the following:

```
# Persistence
dbVendor=postgresql

# Basic connection options
spring.dataSource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.dataSource.url=jdbc:postgresql://is-0001/<database>
spring.dataSource.username=<username>
spring.dataSource.password=<password>

# Hibernate options
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=<package>.ImplicitNamingStrategyImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=<package>.PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl

# Options to create sql scripts
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=/development/projects/<project>/backend/sql/setup/createDb.sql
#spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target=/development/projects/<project>/backend/sql/setup/dropDb.sql
```

For some reason the setting for `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` is ignored  by Spring - independent of its value - whereas the `spring.jpa.properties.javax...` properties are applied correctly which is easy to verify by looking at the generated SQL file (createDb.sql and dropDb.sql).

Does anybody have any idea what the reason for this behaviour could be? I would really be thankful as I have been trying to find the root cause for this issue for more than a day now?

Just as a side node: Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate

You need to set the property: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course, I read the documentation you are referring to. My understanding is that ```spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create``` is just a shorthand for ```spring.jap.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create```. And I have also tested this property with exactly the same result - no tables being created.

Comment: I can confirm that I'm seeing the same issue. I tried setting both "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" and "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" and none of them are being honored. To give some context - for me this happens in my Unit Test Environment, since that's where I'm setting these values.